# iPhoto and unknown RAW Formats

Tags: photos.app

I have a Camera that supports RAW (Panasonic Lumix FZ35), but sadly iPhoto (and Aperture) don't support this format.

Short of reporting Feedback to Apple and hoping for the best, is there any other way to make iPhoto work with this RAW Format, like a "Plugin" that integrates neatly into iPhoto?

I want to avoit having to use Photoshop to edit/convert them to JPG and then put those JPGs into iPhoto.

Comment: If you;re not attached to iPhoto, Lightroom is excellent. Also, Picasa supports a few raw formats, it may work, and is free.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of cameras come with software to convert their RAW files to other formats. If your's comes with conversion then see if it supports regular TIFF.

You might want to look into [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), which is a graphic program from the *nix world that runs under X11 on the Macintosh. It's very similar to Photoshop but is free. It has some auto conversion capability and/or might be able to read your camera's RAW files. [GraphicConverter](http://www.lemkesoft.com/) might be another option. It's got a long list of formats it supports and converts between.

Converting to JPG changes the file format in ways that make it a lot less flexible. I have my own photography company, and only shoot RAW when I'm doing serious work, because I need the flexibility of non-jpeg. I convert to Photoshop format and do all my manipulation in their format, then save a copy of the final image in Adobe's Photoshop format, then make another copy and save it as JPG, ready for sending to the place that does my prints. RAW and TIFF support better color and greater gamut (light range from dark to light) and you can see the difference after converting to jpeg so I want to avoid the conversion until the last step.

Comment: Converting to JPEG losses the benefits of shooting in raw: ability to tune or correct the wrong exposure without losing quality up to 2 stops. He wrote he want to avoid converting in external editor.

Answer (score 0):

Converting to something that isn't RAW means you'll lose data. GIMP and Photoshop are essentially raster image editors so you lose that very useful camera data.

[Silkypix](http://www.silkypix.us) is another good alternative for RAW editing and conversion and it supports a huge list of cameras. It is a non-destructive editor so any editing you do leaves the original file unharmed.